# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in ShopProfiles#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails. I have defined controller for the index of `shop_products` as follows

**shop_profile.rb**

```
class ShopProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_one :shop_inventory_detail
end
```

**shop_product.rb**

```
class ShopProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop_profile
end
```

**shop_products_controller.rb**

```
class ShopProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @shop_profile = ShopProfile.find(params[:shop_profile_id])
    @products = @shop_profile.shop_products
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb in shopprofiles**

```
<%= link_to 'All Products', shop_profile_shop_products_path(@shop_profile) ,class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

on this line I get error that

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in ShopProfiles#index
Showing /home/mindfire/Desktop/project/training/Rails/grocery-shop/app/views/shop_profiles/index.html.erb where line #4 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"shop_products", :shop_profile_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:shop_profile_id]
```

**the routes**

```
shop_profile_shop_products     GET    /users/shop_profiles/:shop_profile_id/shop_products(.:format)          shop_products#index
                               POST   /users/shop_profiles/:shop_profile_id/shop_products(.:format)          shop_products#create
 new_shop_profile_shop_product GET    /users/shop_profiles/:shop_profile_id/shop_products/new(.:format)      shop_products#new
edit_shop_profile_shop_product GET    /users/shop_profiles/:shop_profile_id/shop_products/:id/edit(.:format) shop_products#edit
     shop_profile_shop_product GET    /users/shop_profiles/:shop_profile_id/shop_products/:id(.:format)      shop_products#show
                               PATCH  /users/shop_profiles/:shop_profile_id/shop_products/:id(.:format)      shop_products#update
                               PUT    /users/shop_profiles/:shop_profile_id/shop_products/:id(.:format)      shop_products#update
                               DELETE /users/shop_profiles/:shop_profile_id/shop_products/:id(.:format)      shop_products#destroy
```

And when I pass the `shop_profile_id` manually I get the desired page.
Thanks in advance for any help.

**shop_profiles_controller.rb**

```
class ShopProfilesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!, except: :show
 after_action :verify_authorized, only: :shop_index

 def new
    @shop = ShopProfile.new
 end

 def index
    @shops = current_user.shop_profiles
 end

 def show
    @shop_profile = ShopProfile.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @items = @shop_profile.shop_products.group(:category_id).where(category_id: params[:category_id])
 end

 def create
    @shop = ShopProfile.new(shop_params)
    @shop.build_address(address_params_shopkeeper)
    if current_user.shop_profiles << @shop
        flash[:success] = 'Shop Details added'
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        flash[:error] = 'Shop Details not added'
        render 'new'
    end
 end

 def edit
    @shop = current_user.shop_profiles.find_by(id: params[:id])
 end

 def update
    @shop = current_user.shop_profiles.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @shop.update_attributes(shop_params) and @shop.address.update_attributes(address_params_shopkeeper) 
        flash[:success] = 'Updated Successfully'
        redirect_to shop_profiles_path
    else
        flash[:danger] = 'Shop Details not Updated'
        render 'edit'
    end
 end
end
```

But I think it has nothing to do with shop_profiles_controller.
I was calling the shop_product index page from there.

**error log**

```
Started GET "/users/shop_profiles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-31 16:36:34 +0530
Processing by ShopProfilesController#index as HTML
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Rendered shop_profiles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"shop_products", :shop_profile_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:shop_profile_id]):
 1: <div>
 2:     <%= link_to 'Add Shop' ,new_shop_profile_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
 3:     <%= link_to 'Add New Product', new_product_path, class: 'btn btn-primary', method: :get %>
 4:     <%= link_to 'All Products', shop_profile_shop_products_path(@shop_profile) ,class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
 5: </div>
 6: <div>
 7:     <% if !@shops.nil? %>
app/views/shop_profiles/index.html.erb:4:in   `_app_views_shop_profiles_index_html_erb___2474323268141556614_25251260'


 Rendered /home/mindfire/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@localshop/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (9.0ms)............
```

Comment: Are you sure what `@shop_profile` is not `nil`, have you tried pass an id directly `shop_profile_shop_products_path(@shop_profile.id)` ?

Comment: try this `shop_profile_shop_products_path(shop_profile_id: @shop_profile.id)`

Comment: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in ShopProfiles#index` - Your error says the issue is in `ShopProfilesController`. Can you post your  `ShopProfilesController` controller.

Comment: Passing id directly is showing the desired page.

Comment: In your `ShopProductsController's index action`, you are trying to do `@products = @shop_profile.shop_products`. but I don's see `has_many` association between your `ShopProfile` and `ShopProduct` models

Comment: shop_profile_shop_products_path(shop_profile_id: @shop_profile.id) is not working .Its throwing undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass error

Comment: class ShopProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :address
 has_and_belongs_to_many :users
 has_one :shop_inventory_detail
 has_many :shop_products    end

Comment: @BikramSao can you update your question with `ShopProfilesController` ?

Comment: @BikramSao can you add the complete error log ?

Comment: @dkp I added both.

Comment: `<%= link_to 'All Products', shop_profile_shop_products_path(@shop_profile) ,class: 'btn btn-primary' if @shop_profile.present? %>` - Add this line and see if you still see the **All Products** `link_to` in your view page or not. I think your `@shop_profile` is `nil` here.

Comment: as I notice in the first comment the `@shop_profile` is `nil` also you can see it from the `ShopProfilesController` index action has no such variable `@shop_profile`, that's your problem. __`@shop_profile` is nil__

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Зелёный

From your error log, it looks you are trying to send a `nil` in `shop_profile_shop_products_path` which is causing the issue.

Make sure `@shop_profile` is not `nil`.

You can do the followings if you want to avoid this issue:

```
<%= link_to 'All Products', shop_profile_shop_products_path(@shop_profile) ,class: 'btn btn-primary' if @shop_profile.present? %>
```

Hope it solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for your responses .
The problem was a user can have multiple shop profiles . So I iterate through all shop profiles and call the index method and got the desired page.